# Compton scattering's frequency paradox

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In Compton scattering, the wavelength difference of scattered radiation is measured as, as well as calculated by conservation of momentum:
$\lambda - \lambda'={\frac{h}{mc}} (1-cos\theta)$

where $\lambda$ is incident photon's wavelength, $\lambda '$ is the scattered photon's wavelength, $\theta$ is the scattered angle.

Which means the photon's frequency will change during scattering.

In X-ray interacts with electron, then the frequency difference can be easily measured, given the mass of electron is small.

Q: then I am confused why frequency of EM waves does NOT change during **refraction**, as *it is macroscopically scattering.*

---

A few guesses of mine:

1.)check my assumption:

> 1.a)refraction is a kind of scattering.  (maybe it is NOT,
>   refraction is some quantum phenomenon?)
>
> or
>
> 1.b) I assumed that medium should be homogeneous and linear such
>   that by Maxwell equation the frequency does not change, which is
>   pretty much NOT that case if we look at atoms and electrons.

2.) maybe "frequency does not change" is just an approximation in classical physics? (in a sense refraction has to do with nuclei too, which is much massive than electrons, therefore, the difference will be much harder to measure.) So in real(quantum) world, frequency changes.

Answer (score 1):

Compton scattering is an inelastic process. Some of the photon energy is transferred to the electron, where it goes into increasing the kinetic energy of the electron.

Refraction is an elastic process. No energy is transferred from the light to the medium that the light is travelling through. Well, not for an ideal refractor. In real life nothing is perfectly transparent so some of the light energy is absorbed.

In refraction the oscillating electric field of the light makes the electrons in the refracting medium oscillate. The oscillating electrons then reradiate the light, but with a small phase lag and the phase lag is what causes the velocity of the light to decrease. No energy is lost in this process. There is quite a nice discussion of this mechanism in the amswers to [How does light speed up after coming out of a glass slab?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/153904/how-does-light-speed-up-after-coming-out-of-a-glass-slab).

Comment: Thanks for answering, by an elastic process, it mean exactly the energy is completely absorbed, and then fully released with a phase lag?